# Open Marketplace with publisher`s applications list

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

How can I get Marketplace with publisher`s applications list?
I can open browser with URL www.windowsphone.com/en-us/publishers/[publisherName], but I would prefer to work with Marketplace.
In Android applications it is possible to make a search by parameter "pub:" and to take application list of chosen publisher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use MarketplaceDetailTask  selection contains other apps that aren't refered to this publisher (there are just same words as publisher's name). To solve this problem I've created a page with links to apps of my publisher in each of apps. In this case I can monitor and analyze jumps by those links.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for. You can search for all the apps from a publisher:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394001(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: This search return general application list by search parameters, which gives not only applications of required publisher - it contains other, unwanted search results. In Android applications it is possible to make a search by parameter "pub:<publisher_name>" and to take application list of chosen publisher.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
Dim marketplaceSearchTask As MarketplaceDetailTask = New MarketplaceDetailTask()

marketplaceSearchTask.ContentIdentifier = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

marketplaceSearchTask.Show()
```

it's not actually what you (and me) are searching but it's way more accurate then the previous answer.
replace X-es with your marketplace app link id.